# A beginner question on RxJava and PublishSubject

Tags: java, kotlin, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have question regarding `PublishSubject` in `RxJava`. 
I have created a dummy PublishSubject that emits some objects. Here is my code :

```
override fun generate(exportRequest: ExportRequest): Observable<Report> {
        val faker = Faker()
        val dummyPublisher = PublishSubject.create<Report>()
        for(x in 1..1_000){
            val dataToExport = DataToExport(UUID.randomUUID(), faker.company().buzzword(), faker.company().name())
            val report = Report(dataToExport)
            sddPublisher.onNext(report)
            Thread.sleep(1)
        }
        dummyPublisher.onComplete()
        return dummyPublisher
    }
```

When subscribing, no objects are emitted. For instance for this,  nothing is printed :

```
... // somewhere in the code
reportStrategy.generate(exportRequest).subscribe { report: Report? ->
     println(report)
 }
```

Maybe I am missing something. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is this Java???

Comment: Seems like Kotlin

Comment: `PublishSubject` is there to multicast signals to live observers. You created a private instance of it, fed it items and **then** returned it as completed to the external world so no other observers can ever see the items. You probably need `Observable.create` instead.

Comment: Thx for your insight @akarnokd. This is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @akarnokd in the comments, the `PublishSubject` you create immediately emits any value passed to it by its `onNext` method. This happens whether or not anything is currently subscribed to it. It is designed primarily to help bridge the gap between imperative or callback-based code and reactive code.

What you seem to want is an `Observable` that begins executing some synchronous code once something subscribes to it. `Observable.create` is one way to create such an instance, but it can be cumbersome to use correctly.

A more convenient method for creating what you want is `Observable.fromPublisher`. It takes a `Publisher` as an argument. A `Publisher` is itself a function that is passed a `Subscriber` instance whenever an `Observer` subscribes to the `Observable` created by `fromPublisher` and allows you to send events directly to that `Observer`.

The code you want would look something like this:

```
fun generateReportStream(genFakeReport: () -> Report): Observable<Report> {
    return Observable.fromPublisher { subscriber ->
        for (x in 1..1_000) {
            val fakeReport = genFakeReport()
            subscriber.onNext(fakeReport)
            Thread.sleep(1)
        }
        subscriber.onComplete()
    }
}

fun main() {
    /** supply whatever logic you want to generate a fake [Report] */
    fun genFakeReport(): Report = TODO()
    val subscription = generateReportStream(::genFakeReport).subscribe(::println)
}
```

This will correctly emit values once a subscription is made to the `Observable` instance returned by `generateReportStream`. In addition, more subscriptions may be made to the same instance and each one will emit a fresh sequence values using the same logic.